# Insert text into a WPF textblock from the top

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, textblock

i have a textblock that displays multiline messages that are received continuously from the network along with the time it was received. here is the code:

```
private async Task ReadMessage(TcpClient client, bool ownsClient)
    {
        
            using NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

            int bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            string message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            string receptiontime = now.ToString("HH:mm");
            Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                NotamsTextBlock.Text += "-->" + receptiontime + Environment.NewLine;
                NotamsTextBlock.Text += message;
               
            }), DispatcherPriority.Background);
            
    }
```

Here is how it is displayed in the app: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlATn.png)

By default the new message received is inserted in the textblock after the old message. What i want to do is change it. The new message should be inserted from the top which means that when reading the content of the textblock you always start with the newest message.

Any idea on how i can achieve that?

Thanks.

Ps: i'm not using MVVM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use a `TextBlock` for this task. The `TextBlock` is optimized to display only a few lines at max. It is not designed to display multiline documents.

The recommended solution is to use a `ListBox`. It offers virtualization to provide a smooth scrolling experience.
You can override the default template of the `ListBoxItem` to remove the mouse over and highlight effects. This way the `ListBox` will look like a plain text document or a common console output.
Don't use the `Dispatcher` in this case too. If you need to update the `ObservableCollection`, which is the data source for the `ListBox`, from a background thread, use the `BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization`.

**MessageLine.cs**

```cs
public class MessageLine : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public MessageLine(string message) => this.Message = message;

  public string Message { get; }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;}

  public override string ToString()
    => $"Formatted message content: {this.Message}.";
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public ObservableStack<MessageLine> Messages { get; }

  publiv MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  
    this.Messages = new ObservableStack<MessageLine>();
  }

  private void InsertLineAtBeginning(MessageLine message) => this.Messages.Push(message);

  // Not supported by ObservableStack
  //private void AppendLine(MessageLine message) => this.Messages.Add(message);

  private async Task ReadMessageAsync(TcpClient client, bool ownsClient)
  {
    await using NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
    
    ...

   // Since we insert at the beginning but want to have a proper line order of the multi-line message,
   // we must insert the last line first (reverse order - you can use a Stack to collect the lines)

    string messageBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    InsertLineAtBeginning(new MessageLine(messageBody));   

    var messageHeader = $"-->{receptiontime}";
    InsertLineAtBeginning(new MessageLine(messageHeader));   
  }

  private async void SaveMessages_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    await using var fileWriter = new StreamWriter("destination_file.txt", false);
    foreach (var message in this.Messages)
    {
      // Call ToString() for a defined string representation of the instance.
      // Requires to override ToString to get a useful value. 
      await fileWriter.WriteLineAsync(message.ToString());

      // Alternatively, format message inline
      await fileWriter.WriteLineAsync($"Formatted message content: {message.Message}");
    }
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>
  <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding RlativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType Window}, Path=Messages}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MessageLine}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    
    <!-- Remove interaction effects -->
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
          <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
              <ContenPresenter />
            </ControlTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
      </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
  </ListBox>
</Window>
```

**ObservableStack.cs**

```cs
public class ObservableStack<TItem> : Stack<TItem>, INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public ObservableStack()
  {
  }

  public ObservableStack(IEnumerable<TItem> collection) : base(collection)
  {
  }

  public ObservableStack(int capacity) : base(capacity)
  {
  }

  new public void Push(TItem item)
  {
    base.Push(item);
    OnCountPropertyChanged();
    OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, item, 0));
  }

  new public bool TryPop(out TItem item)
  {
    if (base.TryPop(out item))
    {
      OnCountPropertyChanged();
      OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, item, 0));
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }

  new public void Pop()
  {
    TItem removedItem = base.Pop();
    OnCountPropertyChanged();
    OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, removedItem, 0));
  }

  new public void Clear()
  {
    base.Clear();
    OnCountPropertyChanged();
    OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
  }

  protected virtual void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) => this.CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
  private void OnCountPropertyChanged() => OnPropertyChanged(propertyName: nameof(this.Count));
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    => this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

  public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler? CollectionChanged;
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
}
```

You can also move the `ListBox` to a `UserControl` or custom `Control`.

Comment: Good idea of using Listbox. however i'm having errors on the XAML side the first one is "MessageLine not supported in a WPF project" where you define the DataType and the second is "a value of type ControlTemplate cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'SetterBaseCollection'

Comment: 1) you must always give the namespace to qualify a custom type (the example now uses `local` as the alias). 2) you must use setters in Style. I have improved the example.

Comment: Thanks, it working perfectly although i had to struggle as where to put **BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization** in the code.I finally put it the constructor of the UserControl i'm using it in. One other thing i had to do was to make the scrolling of the ListBox smoother by putting it's property **ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll** to False.

Comment: Putting the `BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization`into the constructor of the control is fine. Generally, it must be invoked on the UI thread. Don't set `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll` to false. This will disable UI virtualization which will make the scrolling slow and sluggish (when many items are loaded). It will freeze. You must leave it on true. ListBox then scrolls item by item (true) which of course feels different than pixel by pixel (false). If you expect many lines (or items) don't set it to false .

Comment: Ok i got it. Thanks. one last question. i'm trying to copy the content of the ListBox in a file. once i loop through the items of the ListBox and use the streamwriter like `sw.WriteLine(item.ToString())` i dont get the right result, instead in the file i see something like **Mynamespace.MessageLine**. Any idea how to convert the item to a string?

Comment: `ToString` will always return the type's name by default. If you want it to return a meaningful representation of the instance, you must override `ToString()` in the corresponding type (see `Message` example above). Alternatively, construct the string inline. I have updated the answer to give you an example. The `SaveMessages_OnClick` method also shows how to use the async API to write to a file. This way writing to a file or stream won't freeze the UI.

Comment: Great! it was easier to use `await fileWriter.WriteLineAsync($"Formatted message content: {message.Message}")`. Thank you very much

Comment: Hi @BionicCode . i have noticed that after a while the application gets very slow specially in the listbox area. i'm guessing it's because the observablecollection becomes very large after all the items being inserted to it. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: @hassanMa It would be interesting what "slow" exactly means? `ListBox` uses UI virtualization, so I doubt the `ListBox` is the reason for bad performance. `Collection.Insert` is O(n) so when the number of items increases the insert operation's performance decreases. I suggest to use a `Stack` where `Stack.Push` basically inserts the item at the beginning but with O(1).

Comment: @hassanMa Because you would bind to the `Stack` dynamically you would have to create your own `ObservableStack` implementation (which is very simple). Just extend the `Stack` class, implement `INotifyCollectionChanged` and override the virtual  `Push` method to raise the `CollectionChanged` event - that's all. If you need to remove items too, override the `Pop` method too to raise the event. this should improve the performance (for big collections). Are you actually using my suggested solution or are you still with your original code?

Comment: I'm using your suggested solution. shall i change the observablecollection to an observablestack? first time hearing about it.

Comment: @hassanMa There is no such class in the .NET library. As I have explained before you must implement it yourself. The point is that collections are optimized for adding items (append to end). Insertion involves moving each item that's why the performance is O(n). Stack on the other hand is optimized for inserting items at the beginning. That's what you need.

Comment: @hassanMa I have added an untested implementation of `ObservableStack`. Using this should improve the insertion performance for large collections. But it does not allow to append (add) items. If you need to **add*  items (in addition to inserting them) you would have to modify the `ObservableStack` accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. i will have a try at it. but ultimately i think we will get to a point where the collection is going to be too big since the application receive maybe hundreds of messages per day unless we restart the application which is not optimal. i was thinking about a way to only keep a certain number of items in collection at a time if its possible.

Comment: You can partition the collection/ListBox into pages for example 100 items per page. This way your collection only contains 1 or two pages. This is called data virtualization.

Comment: Additionally you can back it up using a local database like SQLite. This way you would reduce the memory footprint and can search for messages very fast..

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. In my case though there may be an easier way. In fact i don't need to display all the content of the collection. in fact i really just need let's say the first ten messages each time. Since i process each message as it comes, the collection is only used for display purposes. so maybe if possible use a second collection that always contains the first 10 items of the first collection and bind it to the listbox unless the data virtualization does exactly what i'm describing. just note that in my case i don't need all the collection.

Answer (score 0):

I put a TextBlock and a button on a WPF window as test. And this works:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp7;

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        myTextBlock.Text = "Before";
    }

    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myTextBlock.Text = myTextBlock.Text.Insert(0, "after");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Kelly. In my case when i use this method i don't get the result i'm looking for